# Jquery optimize biggest height determination

Tags: jquery, css

**REAL PROBLEM:**
I have a `ul` of `li.column`, which line themselves up horizontally and wraps to the next line automatically using `float:left` css trick. (I hope this trick is common enough that most of you understand what I am doing?)

And because each `li` actually contain image links of equal width, I'm forcing the li themselves to have equal width as well, so that the anchor element will wrap its text around in case its too long.

Now, unfortunately I have one of the `<li><a>LONG TEXT</a></li>` being wrapped and inevitably increased the height of its `li` container, which then breaks the CSS layout of the next rows.

I want to set the height for all `li.columns` to match this height instead, but want to do it programatically using jquery.

So this is my partial code:

```
var allColumns = $('li.column');
allColumns
.css('width','225px')
.css('padding-right','20px').css('background-color','transparent');
$('li.column:nth-child('+numCol+'n)').css('padding-right','0px');

var maxHeight = 0;
allColumns.each( function(index, item) {
  var height = $(item).height();
  if ( height > maxHeight ) { maxHeight = height; }
} );
allColumns.height(maxHeight);
```

Is there anything I can do to avoid the `each` loop to obtain maxHeight using something more native (optimized)?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the answer to this question is that there is no magic answer. That really is the way to do it.

However, it seems right now you are tailoring your `<li>` elements to fit the size of your content. Another way to do it would be to fit your content to your `<li>` elements (doing this may depend on your project's requirements) You could try these css rules. All of the following rules will allow you to manipulate how your columns will handle the longer amount of text. If you can get away with it, you wouldn't need to do any JQuery work

`white-space:nowrap;`

`overflow:scroll;` or `overflow:hidden;`